# Simplifying a set of shapes into a single shape

Tags: algorithm, geometry

Given you have a bunch of shapes, say like this:

[image]

Wondering if there is a real-time algorithm out there (or any suggestions would be helpful too) that can identify that you can approximate that with large circles sort of like this:

[image]

It doesn't have to be circles specifically, it can be parameterized to work in different ways. Just wondering how to basically:

1. Identify a chunk of shapes that can be approximated by a simpler shape.
2. Overlay that shape on top of the more complex/smaller shapes.

Thank you.

Comment: I think this question is a little to broad, do you have any other constraints?
How about drawing a grid and filling all grid cells that intersect with the original shapes?

Comment: That's what I'm wondering, not sure exactly how you would do that. Just being able to do (1) would be totally enough help. Not sure how to go about doing the identifying at a high level. It doesn't need to include details such as using a quad tree to do efficient lookups or whatnot, just looking for high-level guidance. Thank you again.

Comment: What you are asking is more a task for humans than for computers.

Comment: So what is wrong with the grid approach? I agree with Yves Daoust that in order to develop an algorithm you need a better definition of you objective. This could for example look like this: (1) I have a set P of polygons in 2D (2) and a set of simple polygons Q (3) Find an overlay O of the polygons in P with the polygons in Q (4) the polygons in Q can be rotated, resized and reused (5) The objective is to find an overlay such that |O intersect P| is minimal and we use not more than k polygons from Q.

Comment: Yes that is a very accurate description :D Still trying to wrap my head around the grid approach.

Comment: The grid approach is very simple, just draw a grid over your image and fill every grid cell that is covered with enough of your shapes. You can vary the grid size in order to get more or less rectangles. For example like in this image https://pasteboard.co/H8NOJBG.png

Comment: I would try to extract major contours (Blur + edge detect) and detect if they are any of basic shape (based on their properties like aspect ratio vs area number of edges and point density...) then convert/fit it to/by it. However such approach would convert your image to 2 discs one big with avg color and second smaller black centered inside it as a hole...

Answer (score 1):

I think of an approach. I would call it **Changing Contrast/Brightness** as in image edit applications.

1. you get all the centers of your shapes.
2. get their volumes.
3. calculate the weight of each shape (function of distance and volume of each other shape. Wx = F(Di, Vi), where W (Weight), x: your current shape index, D (distance), Di the distance between x and i, V (Volume), Vi : the volume of i.
4. Have a variable (perhaps a value scroll bar) to change the **Brightness**.
5. repeat #4 for **Contrast**.
6. Calculate the average (or mean average) of Weight of all shapes.

Increasing the Brightness means decreasing the volume of far shapes (i.e. shapes with weight below the average "low weight").

Increasing the contrast means increase volume of shapes of high weight and decrease low weights.

By changing both contrast and brightness, some shapes will disappear, others will join as one shape, and you will get a simpler shape(s).